# How can I change the Font of a TListBox's items?

Tags: firemonkey, vcl, rad-studio

I'm building an app with RAD Studio 11, but I can't find a way to change the item font of my `TListBox`.

[image: App]

I tried to change `TListBox.Font` in the Object Inspector, but when I select my `TListBox` called `ingredientsDataBase` in the Object Inspector, I can just change `TListBox` settings instead of `TListBox.Items` settings.

[image: Object Inspector]

I add a `TListBoxItem` manually as follow:

[image: ListBoxItem]

Then, I can change `ListBoxItem1.Font` in the Object Inspector, after selecting my `ListBoxItem1` (no problem).

[image: ListBoxItem1 Font changed]

The problem is that, when I run my program, the `Font` change only affects my `ListBoxItem1`, and I want the same `Font` for every item that I add to my `TListBox`.

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

After your help I tried to convert your Delphi code to C++.

```
__fastcall TIngredientCreator::addButtonClick(TObject *Sender){
        //More code Here
        //Then I ADD a new ListBoxItem to my ListBox "ingredientsDataBase"
        ingredientsDataBase->Items->Add("newIngredient");

        TListBoxItem *lbItem = new TListBoxItem(ingredientsDataBase);
        lbItem->Parent = ingredientsDataBase;

        // Remove Family and Size from the items TStyledSettings
        lbItem->StyledSettings = lbItem->StyledSettings << TStyledSetting::Family << TStyledSetting::Size;

        // You can now set these TextSettings as needed
        lbItem->TextSettings->Font->Family = "Algerian";
        lbItem->TextSettings->Font->Size = 18;
        lbItem->Text = "algerian";

        delete lbItem;
    }
```

There is no syntax error, but I can't associate my new `ListBoxItem`, in this case the `Text` or `Name` of that new `ListBoxItem` called `"newIngredient"` (I don't know how to do it in this code), so when I run my program nothing happen to mi new Item at least.

**UPDATE 2**

I found a way to associate my newIngredient to `TListBoxItem` Object as follow:

```
 int index = ingredientsDataBase->Items->IndexOf(newIngredient);
lbItem = ingredientsDataBase->ItemByIndex(index);
```

When I run the code and I add a new Ingredient, just the `Text` of the newIngredient is changed to "algerian", because in the first code I have this line `lbItem->Text = "algerian"` all good here. But Font and Size still without change.

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add items to the listbox, you need to clear some items from the default `StyledSettings` property of the new item, if you want to modify the corresponding `TextSettings`.

Here's an example in Delphi to do what you want:

```
procedure TForm5.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lbItem: TListBoxItem;
begin
  lbItem := TListBoxItem.Create(ListBox1);
  lbItem.Parent := ListBox1;
  // Remove Family and Size from the items TStyledSettings
  lbItem.StyledSettings := lbItem.StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.Family,TStyledSetting.Size];
  // You can now set these TextSettings as needed
  lbItem.TextSettings.Font.Family := 'Algerian';
  lbItem.TextSettings.Font.Size := 18;
  lbItem.Text := 'algerian';

  // In Embarcadero C++Builder you use the ">>" operator to remove members from a set, and "<<" to include them.
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have worked on the code you sent me, but I still have problem, I added to my post how I convert your Delphi to c++ code and how I implemented to my application, but the problem still there. I really apreciate your help.

Comment: But I told you to **remove** items from `StyledSettings` in order to change corresponding `TextSettings`. And further, "use the `>>` operator to remove members from a set". In your code you are using `<<`.

Answer (score 0):

After your help my code in a Multi-Device Application C++ Builder project result on the next code:

```
   __fastcall TIngredientCreator::addButtonClick(TObject *Sender){
        
        //More code Here
        //Then I ADD a new ListBoxItem to my ListBox "ingredientsDataBase"
        ingredientsDataBase->Items->Add("newIngredient");

        int index = ingredientsDataBase->Items->IndexOf(newIngredient);
        lbItem = ingredientsDataBase->ItemByIndex(index);

        // Remove Family and Size from the items TStyledSettings
        lbItem->StyledSettings = lbItem->StyledSettings >> TStyledSetting::Family >> TStyledSetting::Size;

        // You can now set these TextSettings as needed
        lbItem->TextSettings->Font->Family = "Consolas";
        lbItem->TextSettings->Font->Size = 18;

        delete lbItem;
    }
```

If you are trying to do it in a Windows VCL Aplication C++ Builder Project is easier (You can change the font of the entire TListBox once):

```
    ingredientsDataBase->Font->Size = 8.5;
    ingredientsDataBase->Font->Name = "Consolas";
```